# Mongoose Connection Keeps Closing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Node.js app that should run forever and am creating a single mongodb connection. However the connection keeps closing after a few seconds and crashing the app. I've stripped all the code back to just the create connection method. App code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    db = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost:28017/mwa");
```

Then after a few seconds I get:

```
node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: connection closed
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/gavin/mwa/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:557:24)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:88:20)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/gavin/mwa/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:109:15)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:70:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/gavin/mwa/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:427:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Array.0 (net.js:335:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Comment: Have you checked if MongoDB is restarting when this happens?  Check its log file for issues that make it kill your connection.

Comment: The log didn't reveal anything, however your comment prompted me to try restarting mongo. That did work :) If you add that as an answer I will accept ;)

Comment: OK, I added an answer to that effect.

Comment: Not sure about MongoDB, but in most (traditional databases) it's better to open/close the connection on demand rather than leaving it open forever. The database drivers are usually optimized to create and manage a pool connections behind the scenes so this (opening/closing) tends to be incredibly fast.

Comment: mongod listens on port 27017 by default and web-stats are available on 28017. Hope there's no mix-up on the port numbers to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check MongoDB's log file to see if it's hitting any issues that are making it kill your connection.  As you mention, restarting MongoDB would be a good thing to try if there's nothing in the log.